# Compute $\iint_D(x^2-y^2)^{10}dxdy,$ where $D$ is bounded by $|x|+|y|\leq 1.$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> Compute $$\iint_D(x^2-y^2)^{10}dxdy,$$ where $D$ is bounded by
>   $|x|+|y|\leq 1.$

I'm supposed to solve this by introducing new variables by $u=x-y$ and $v=x+y.$ I get that $$\iint_D(x^2-y^2)^{10}dxdy=\iint_E(uv)^{10}\cdot \frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)} dudv.$$

I have that $$\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}=\begin{vmatrix} x'_{u} & x'_{v} \\ y'_{u} & y'_{v} \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{vmatrix}=1=\text{no scaling.}$$

So it boils down to $$\iint_E(uv)^{10}dudv.$$

I'm having trouble understanding the bounds. What are the bounds in $D$ and in $E$? I did the following:

$$|x|+|y|\leq 1 \Leftrightarrow -1+|x| \leq y \leq 1-|x|,$$ So my area $D$ is a triangle bounded by $x=0, \ y = -1+x$ and $y=1-x.$ How do I translate these bounds w.r.t $(u,v)?$

Comment: Your area $D$ is a diamond with vertices $(1,0), (0,1), (-1,0), (0,-1)$.

Comment: I call that diamond a "square".

Comment: @MartinArgerami Sure, you can call $\diamond$ a square. Up to you.

Comment: You should double check your Jacobian calculation.

Answer (score 1):

If to move forward, you want, then reflect upon your past work. Needs attention first, your Jacobian does. Find $x$ and $y$ in terms of $u$ and $v$, you must. Solve linear system
$$u=x-y,\qquad v=x+y$$
to find
$$x=\frac{u+v}{2},\qquad y=\frac{v-u}{2}$$
Find a different Jacobian, you will
$$\frac{d(x,y)}{d(u,v)}=\begin{vmatrix}\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\\-\frac{1}{2}&\frac{1}{2}\end{vmatrix}=\frac{1}{2}$$
Not triangular, but diamond shape, your original domain $D$ is. To image shape of new domain, you must imagine reshaping your original diamond through a linear transformation, hmm?
$$|x|+|y|\leq1\implies|u+v|+|u-v|\leq2$$
$\qquad\qquad\qquad$[image] $\quad\implies$ [image]

A rotation, the transformation is. Finish the problem now, can you?

Comment: Without using WolframAlpha, I know that the transformation rotates, how?

Comment: @Parseval: $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 \\ 1 & -1\end{pmatrix}$$ is an orthogonal matrix, hence $x\mapsto\frac{u+v}{\sqrt{2}}, y\mapsto \frac{u-v}{\sqrt{2}}$ encodes a $45^\circ$ rotation around the origin.